# Why LIKE is giving error in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have database in which a table operator_details has two columns...

```
mobile_prefix    operator

9899              idea
9214              airtel
```

like this, now I am trying a query in which if the number is 9899745214 ., it should return IDEA.
I am trying it in this way...

```
SELECT operator 
FROM operator_details
WHERE mobile_prefix + '%' LIKE '9899745214'
```

i HAVE ALSO TRIED LIKE THIS :-

```
SELECT operator 
FROM operator_details
WHERE '9899745214' LIKE  mobile_prefix + '%'
```

But both giving errors... where have i done mistake???

Comment: what datatype is `mobile_prefix`?

Comment: mobile_prefix is char(4)

Comment: The string concatenation operator in MySQL is the function `concat()`, not the `+` sign.

Comment: thanks with concat() its done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something like:

```
SELECT operator 
FROM operator_details
WHERE mobile_prefix = LEFT('9899745214', 4)
```

Comment: Sounds better than using a `LIKE` condition in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
WHERE mobile_prefix LIKE '%'+'9899745214'+'%'
```

Comment: Your query produces an error: [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73b99f/5).

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING`

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT operator FROM tbl
WHERE mob_pre = SUBSTRING('9899745214',1,4)
```

### **[FIND FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9649/10)**

Comment: By using `SUBSTRING` you are getting to an exact match.  You would be better off using `=` instead of `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are tying to perform string operations in mysql query which is not allowed.You should use functions like concat('','')  to achieve this.
Db **column name** must be followed by **where** clause.but in your 2nd case, you are directly giving value for where clause which is not allowed